# Unorthodox routing, vias and fills everywhere

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

The board I'm working on has a (for me) difficult chip. I find my solutions somewhat strange. I can't remember proper boards I have seen using this kind of routing so I ask.

First question about these routes joining together. That just looks awful. Especially those three pins in the top left corner of the chip in the middle. How do professional people deal with this? See first pic: (@winny, is this close enough?)

[image: joining traces]

The second question is about the ground pins routed under the chip. :D There are vias under in the middle anyway because of the ground pad and heat, so I thought I just connect the ground pins to that. Again, this looks plain wrong. See second pic:
[image]

Actually, now as I'm looking at that second screenshot, that's about the worse job I have ever seen. :(

Comment: If that's the worst you've ever seen, do I have some horror stories to tell you!

Comment: If C1 and C3 are meant to be decoupling, I'd probably try to put them closer to the voltage pins.  You've got a fair amount of space in between not doing much.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is perfectly fine.

Many folks would tend to just stitch directly from pin 14 to 15 and 15 to 16 (as you have done). Same with pin 17 to 18. There are cases where we might create a single large rectangle that covers pins 17 and 18 and then come out to the left. Same with pins 26 and 1.

Tying the grounds to the pad under the IC as you did is common. I think you show a copper pad under the IC there, which is needed.

If you are doing volume assembly then you work with the assembly house on some details. If you have super high speed or EMI concerns then there are issues to think about. But for general purpose hand soldered work not much is critical.